# Painting of a girl comes to life as a real person

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie when I was very young, maybe around 1990s. It’s an old movie, in which the protagonist is a painter and whatever he paints comes to life (at least that’s how I remember). He painted a girl and she comes to life as in real person and into to the real world. Forgot rest of the story, but in climax, she goes back inside the painting as in cartoon and now she looks like a cartoon on the painting. The protagonist talks with her and draws a black flower on her hand as a farewell gift, she smells the flower and bid farewell. And that’s how the movie ends. What film is this from?

Comment: I haven't seen the film for ages, but I believe that  the film "Allegro Non Troppo" features an animator who draws a girl (prehaps the cleaner), then they both enter the picture as animated characters. If this sounds familiar, you can try and skim the movie on youtube.

Comment: unfortunately, not this one. thanks :)